# How to write a dynamic function for my angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-function

I have a problem to write this code dynamically.

How can I write `testtest` function dynamically, if in the future data could have different keys and values?

my json object looks just like this:

```js
data = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      id: 1,
      colour: 'Green',
      pet: 'Dog'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sarah',
      id: 2,
      colour: 'Purple',
      pet: 'Cat'
    },
    {
      name: 'Lindsay',
      id: 3,
      colour: 'Blue',
      pet: 'Lizard'
    },
    {
      name: 'Megan',
      id: 4,
      colour: 'Orange',
      pet: 'Dog'
    }
];
```

and I have a filtervalue

```js
filterValues = {
    name: '',
    id: '',
    colour: '',
    pet: ''
};
```

now a function

```
createFilter(): (data: any, filter: string) => boolean {
    let filterFunction = function(data, filter): boolean {
        let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
        let result = this.testtest(data, searchTerms);
        return result;
    }
    return filterFunction;
}

testtest(data, searchTerms): boolean {
    return data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.name) !== -1
        && data.id.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.id) !== -1
        && data.colour.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.colour) !== -1
        && data.pet.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.pet) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
testtest(data, searchTerms): boolean {
var result = false;
for (var property in data) {
if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
     result = ( property.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms[property]) !==-1 )
     if(!result){
       return result;
     }   
}
else {
  return result;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that with ES6 -

```
data.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => obj[key] == searchText));
```

Comment: OP has `searchTerms` (object, propably of structure like `filterValues`), not `searchText` (string)

Comment: agree. he can have any structure and any filter or search logic. I just helped him how to use short syntax to filter.

Comment: But since OP uses `data.name`, `data.id`, etc. in their code, they propably use Angular pipes, so using `data.filter` is not needed